# Write map to a csv in python

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am not sure if the title of this is right. I know it is not a list and I am trying to take the results into a dictionary, but it is only adding the last value of my loop.

So I have pasted all my code but I have a question specifically on my candidates loop, where I am trying to get the percentages of votes per candidate. When I print the information it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZwsW.png)

As you can see the 3rd session of the results is showing the candidates and next to them the percentage and the total votes. This results is what I am not sure what is (not a list not a dictionary)

I am trying to write this in my output csv, however after so many ways **I always get to write only the last result which is O'Tooley.**

I am new at this, so I am not sure first, why even if I save my percentage in a list after each loop, I am still saving only the percentage of O'Tooley. That's why I decided to print after each loop. That was my only way to make sure all the results look as in the picture.

```
import os
import csv

electiondatapath = os.path.join('../..','gt-atl-data-pt-03-2020-u-c', '03-Python', 'Homework', 'PyPoll', 'Resources', 'election_data.csv')


with open (electiondatapath) as csvelectionfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvelectionfile, delimiter=',')

# Read the header row first 
    csv_header = next(csvelectionfile)

    #hold number of rows which will be the total votes
    num_rows = 0

    #total votes per candidate
    totalvotesDic = {}

    #list to zip and write to csv
    results = []


    for row in csvreader:

        #total number of votes cast
        num_rows += 1

        # Check if candidate in the dictionary keys, if is not then add the candidate to the dictionary and count it as one, else sum 1 to the votes
        if row[2] not in totalvotesDic.keys():
            totalvotesDic[row[2]] = 1
        else:
            totalvotesDic[row[2]] += 1

print("Election Results")
print("-----------------------")
print(f"Total Votes: {(num_rows)}")
print("-----------------------")

#get the percentage of votes and print result next to candidate and total votes
for candidates in totalvotesDic.keys():
    #totalvotesDic[candidates].append("{:.2%}".format(totalvotesDic[candidates] / num_rows))
    candidates_info = candidates, "{:.2%}".format(totalvotesDic[candidates] / num_rows), "(", totalvotesDic[candidates], ")"
    print(candidates, "{:.2%}".format(totalvotesDic[candidates] / num_rows), "(", totalvotesDic[candidates], ")")

#get the winner out of the candidates
winner = max(totalvotesDic, key=totalvotesDic.get)

print("-----------------------")
print(f"Winner: {(winner)}")
print("-----------------------")

#append to the list to zip
results.append("Election Results")
results.append(f"Total Votes: {(num_rows)}")
results.append(candidates_info)
results.append(f"Winner: {(winner)}")

# zip list together
cleaned_csv = zip(results)

# Set variable for output file
output_file = os.path.join("output_Pypoll.csv")

#  Open the output file
with open(output_file, "w") as datafile:
    writer = csv.writer(datafile)

    # Write in zipped rows
    writer.writerows(cleaned_csv)
```

Comment: Append content of ``candidates_info `` using ``+=`` instead of ``=``. That's why you are getting the last one. Probably you'll need to create ``candidates_info = ""`` variable before the for loop.

Comment: @TomásDenisReyesSánchez Thanks!. Unfortunately I got an error. TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str. I think this is exactly why it is only appending or writing one line. Do you know how could I solve this?

Comment: I think @Selim solution is valid. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, you created a variable named candidates_info for just one candidate. You need to concatenate strings like this example:

```py
candidates_info = ""
for candidates in totalvotesDic.keys():
    candidates_info =  '\n'.join([candidates_info, candidates + "{:.2%}".format(totalvotesDic[candidates] / num_rows) + "("+ str(totalvotesDic[candidates])+ ")"])

print(candidates_info)

# prints
# O'Tooley 0.00%(2)
# Someone 30.00%(..)
```

Also, you don't need `keys()`. Try this instead:

```py
candidates_info = ""
for candidates, votes in totalvotesDic.items():
    candidates_info =  '\n'.join([candidates_info, str(candidates) + "{:.2%}".format(votes / num_rows) + "("+ str(votes)+ ")"])
```